# Can't seem to get hover for drop down menu to work via CSS

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to get a handle on web designing and such (again). Haven't practiced in a long long time, I've been doing tutorials via codecademy.

Now I wanted to edit the code myself and change things as much as i could.

I can't seem to get the drop down menu to work. I got it to work using javascript toggle but I don't like that I have to reclick the menu to close it, and I'd much prefer the hover method via css as its also simpler (or so i thought lol).

now a lot of the examples I've seen use the pound sign " # ", I don't understand why, I've always known to use " .whatever " for my class selector.

my html code for the section i wanted the drop down menu for:

```
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href=# class="dropdown-toggle">Join a Clan<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/platoons/view/4707849498545743143/">Warriors[WAR]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/crew/twizted">Twizted[TWIZ]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

and entire CSS for it:

```
    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }
    /* Header */
     .header {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    /* Menu */
     .header .menu {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .menu > li {
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .menu a {
        color: #898989;
    }



/* Dropdown */
     .dropdown-menu:hover {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        min-width: 105px;
    }
    .dropdown-menu:hover li a {
        color: #898989;
        padding: 6px 20px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }


    /* Carousel */
     .slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 470px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .slide {
        background-size: cover;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .active-slide {
        display: block;
    }
    .slide-copy h1 {
        color: #363636;
        font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 105px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .slide-copy h2 {
        color: #b7b7b7;
        font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .slide-copy p {
        color: #959595;
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        line-height: 1.75em;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
    .slide-img {
        text-align: right;
    }
    /* Slide feature */
     .slide-feature {
        text-align: center;
        height: 470px;
    }
    .slide-feature img {
        margin-top: 112px;
        margin-bottom: 28px;
    }
    .slide-feature a {
        display: block;
        color: #6fc5e0;
        font-family:"HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .slider-nav {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .arrow-prev {
        margin-right: 45px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 9px;
    }
    .arrow-next {
        margin-left: 45px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 9px;
    }
    .slider-dots {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .slider-dots li {
        color: #bbbcbc;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .slider-dots li.active-dot {
        color: #363636;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `:hover` on the wrong element. Try this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-width: 105px;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #898989;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: ha! that's awesome lol, how could I screw that up so bad...thank you! Now here's another question related to your fix. When my mouse hovers over it, it pops up, but when i try to move down to the menu itself, it disappears. I tried to fix the margin sizes thinking maybe something is over lapping but no go.

any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, not [seeing](http://jsfiddle.net/x1217tqb/) that exactly. I do see the menu flicker on/off when moving the mouse around to the right of the drop down link. Not sure what is causing that, possibly because the link jumps to the left when hovering due to the added width of the menu items.

Comment: try `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}.dropdown-menu:hover{display:block;}` it's becasue you're not hovering the .dropdown li when you move the mouse

Comment: @DonBottstein ok so I quickly slapped this to a codecademy sample to show you exactly what's happening. Hover over the Join a clan/video and you'll see.
http://jsfiddle.net/esdskya0/3/

Comment: @Billy tried that out, didn't seem to change anything, if i move my mouse a bunch of times over it really fast, i'll eventually catch the menu though lol

Comment: It's because you're not moving the mouse fast enough. :-D j/k Looks like it has to do with the top margin/padding of the .dropdown-menu element, which is set to 2+5px. If I set padding-top and margin-top to 0 on ul.dropdown-menu, it works flawlessly. For some reason, mousing over the padding/margin is an issue...not sure how to fix that off-hand.

Comment: LOL i should tell users to just move their mouse up n down really fast, haha....dude, thank you so much! I been going over everything i could think of. You fixed my issues! I will go over the padding/margin issues and see if there are other ways that this can be fixed by.

Thanks again for all the help Don Bottstein and @Billy